# How to extract all words in a noun food category in WordNet?

Tags: python, nltk, python-3.7, wordnet

I am trying to get all the words in Wordnet dictionary that are of type noun and category food.

I have found a way to check if a word is noun.food but I need the reverse method:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def if_food(word):
    syns = wn.synsets(word, pos = wn.NOUN)
    for syn in syns:
        print(syn.lexname())
        if 'food' in syn.lexname():
            return 1
    return 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think I have found a solution:

```
# Using the NLTK WordNet dictionary check if the word is noun and a food.
import nltk
nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def if_food(word):

    syns = wn.synsets(str(word), pos = wn.NOUN)

    for syn in syns:
        if 'food' in syn.lexname():
            return 1
    return 0
```

Then using the `qdapDictionaries::GradyAugmented` R English words dictionary I have checked each word if it's a noun.food:

```
en_dict = pd.read_csv("GradyAugmentedENDict.csv")

en_dict['is_food'] = en_dict.word.apply(if_food)

en_dict[en_dict.is_food == 1].to_csv("en_dict_is_food.csv")
```

It it actually did the job.

Hope it will help others.